# Wordpress - Get part of taxonomy name

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

can help me?

I'm trying to get part of name to taxonomy.

Taxonomy slug: **temporada-01**

I only need the number: **01**

I've this code, but this display the name.

```
 <?php 
   $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'temporada' );
    if ( $terms != null ){
     foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        print $term->name;
        unset($term);
     } 
    } 
?>
```

How can retrieve part of the name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a preg_replace() function which will only keep digits:

```
print preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $term->name );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try get_term_by('id', $post->ID, 'taxonomy_name')
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by

Comment: This wil return the taxonomy ID, no? I'll try. Thanks